# Get text outline in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, fonts, flash-builder

I have a flash application and i am trying to create a hand write effect, it will have to draw the outline of the text , so i need the outline of the text , I could have got it if it is predefined fonts , but my users can upload fonts too , so is there any way i can extract outlines of a text in run time? any help is appreciated

I know about `readGraphicsData`, but it wont help!

Answer (score 0):

We had this question before (can't find it). It boils down to this:

There's afaik no trivial way to access the vector outline of text. Yes, you can read the font file (like any other file) and just parse it. Any font description file obviously includes the font outline in some way. You'd have to read the specification of that font file and extract the desired information accordingly.

For example, according to [the OpenType specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Typography/OpenTypeSpecification.aspx)'s [Font File Tables](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm#otttables), the **Tables Related to TrueType Outlines** contain a [glyph tag](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/glyf.htm) wherein you can find `numberOfContours`, `xCoordinates[ ]`, `yCoordinates[ ]`, etc.
I haven't come across a library that reads font description files and extracts that data conveniently, so you'd have to parse it yourself, which is - just to be clear here - an insane amount of work. You could try to find a library in some other language like C and see if you can somehow use it in As3. That might be less work, but it's complicated.

However, there's a flaw in your premise anyway:

> I have a flash application and i am trying to create a hand write effect, it will have to draw the outline of the text

There's pretty much no way to accomplish this. In order to do this, knowing the outline is not enough. To write each glyph, a number of strokes are made. There's no general way to know how a glyph would be written by hand only from its outline.

If you know the outline of an

```
A
```

nothing tells you that the steps to handwrite it are

1. `/`
2. `\`
3. `––`

Fonts might have additional lines. If I wanted to use a service that produces handwriting from a font that I supply, I'd be inclined to use a calligraphic font with plenty of additional loops, curves, etc. **There's no trivial way to automate this.**